# Implement parse SDK with Intel XDK?

Tags: parsing, intel-xdk

How do I implement the parse API with a Intel XDK project?? Couldn't find a way.

I've tried using the local plugin implementation, but it said it couldn't find a plugin in the specified folder so I don't think that's the right one.

Comment: Where did you find the plugin?

Comment: Do you mean the API for https://www.parse.com/ ?

Comment: No, a plugin for Intel XDK that can get the API from parse

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? - https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin